# Transformation of a variable

Tags: transformation, change-of-variable

Let say $x$ is a continuous variable such that $-a\leq x\leq a$, $a>0$. Is there any way to transform this variable so that the resultant variable can take any value in real line?

I am looking for some $1:1$ transformation so that I can also make reverse transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Here are several examples:
$$x \rightarrow \tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2 a}\right).$$
$$x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x/a-1}+\frac{1}{x/a+1}.$$

Comment: For the second transformation, which appears to be quadratic, how can I reverse transform i.e. from $(-Inf, +Inf)$ to $[-a, a]$?

Comment: It is not quadratic.

Comment: Another popular one is $$x\mapsto \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}.$$

Comment: @Doug  If I consider $y = \frac{1}{x/a-1}+\frac{1}{x/a+1}$ then I get an equation like $Ax^2 + Bx + c = 0$ to solve for x (as for reverse transformation). Can you please elaborate why then you say it is not quadratic?

Comment: @Bogaso, finding inverse transformation would be finding the inverse function $y^{-1}$, where $y = 1/(x/a-1)+1/(x/a+1)$.  This is not the same as solving the equation $y(x) = x$.  If you compute the inverse function, it is not a quadratic.

Comment: @Doug I think I could not explain properly. By `inverse function` I meant to say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function. It is not $1/y$. My question is if $y = \frac{1}{x/a-1}+\frac{1}{x/a+1}$ then how can I express $x$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: Yes, @Bogaso, I understand.  If you want to easily find the inverse function, just use symbolab.  It will show you the steps.